# Setting UIImageView image affects layout constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am creation a simple UIImageView with the following constraints:

```
self.view.addConstraint(imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLayoutGuide.topAnchor))
self.view.addConstraint(imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor))
self.view.addConstraint(imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLayoutGuide.heightAnchor))
self.view.addConstraint(imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentLayoutGuide.heightAnchor))
```

The important one is the last one, which sets the width equal to the height of the image view and the height of the image view is being defined by top and bottom anchor.

Now this looks perfectly fine (see image below)
[image: example image view]

However when setting `imageView.image` the image is all over the screen and way too big.
This debugging process fixes it:

```
po for cn in self.imageView!.constraints { cn.isActive = false }
po CATransaction.flush()
```

This makes the image fit inside the imageView as it is intended but up until this point, the imageView is messed up.

What is interesting, before setting the image, the imageView itself does not have any constraints and then setting the image creates those two:

```
- 0 : <NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6040002b2120 UIImageView:0x7fa98f757b90.width == 488 Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750   (active)>
- 1 : <NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x6040002b2180 UIImageView:0x7fa98f757b90.height == 487 Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750   (active)>
```

Those constraints seem to break it, because disabling them fixes the problem. They are only added when setting an image

Comment: Did you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` on the `imageView`?

Comment: yes, of course. otherwise the constraints would break by default

Comment: Did you set the content mode of the image view to aspect fit?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to lower the content compression/hugging. I think (correct me if I am wrong) the UIImageView has by default a higher compression/hugging resistance than a UIView (251 to 250). You could try the code below:

```
someImage.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 249), for: .horizontal)
someImage.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 249), for: .horizontal)
someImage.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 249), for: .vertical)
someImage.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 249), for: .vertical)
```

Comment: using .defaultLow (250) also works, by default it seems to be .defaultHigh, which (750) which causes this bug

Comment: Image doesn't have setContentHuggingPriority and setContentHuggingPriority. ImageView does. I have the same issue but in my case the solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

try to set `clipsToBounds` property to true for UIImageView and check, since for few contentMode options the image goes out of bound of image view if the bounds are not enough to fill the content.

Answer (score 2):

Is your `UIImageView` masking to bounds? If the image is bigger than the `UIImageView` then by default it will extend past the bounds

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Alternatively have you tried changing the content fit of the `UIImageView` to Aspect Fit for example?

Comment: For my case, this worked. I have a tableviewcell views with autolayout constraints, wherein the UIImageView is placed to the left, and placed side by side to the right of  UILabels. But somehow my UILabels overlap the UIImageView by some weird margins. This workaround has solved my issue.