# xcode 10 always render @2x image in storyboard which create constraint issue?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, xcode10

I have generate my project in xcode 9.3 and everything works well. All the storyboard design looks proper but after installing xcode 10 all image display too big and it will not fit inside the view controller bounds.

> **Look like this one.**

[image]

I checked image size and found that it render @2x image from folder. I added @1x image and check same storyboard but no luck can someone help me out in this.

**Update**:

> Check below screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675682/setting-uiimageview-image-affects-layout-constraints/46676145#46676145

Comment: @J.Doe you solution didnot work for me image display as it is.

Comment: @chiragshah I have the same issue. After upgrading to Xcode 10, all the images in storyboard look very big. Any solution for this?

Comment: @shravani No there is no solution yet. Right now i give @ 1x height and width with placeholder constraint. Means it will remove when application run but this is workaround.